# different symbols in a google charts scatter plot

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using the google charts library to make some interactive scatter plots. And  I cannot find is whether you can have symbols other than circles as "markers" ? As far as I can see it was possible with the previous obsolete version of google charts. But is it impossible with the current one ?

Scatter chart "playground":
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#scatter_chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (as of July, 2013) there is no way to do this within the chart options. You have a choice between circles and no markers, and that's it.

You could go through the code and change the SVG using javascript, changing the circles to rectangles, and manipulating the coordinates appropriately (or drawing paths, or whatever you'd like). That's really the only way to do it.

Edited to add:

Additionally, you could set a fill for the circles themselves using javascript, and make the fill any shape you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I suspected. It is surprising how such an important bit is missing... It doesn't even seem possible to make circles empty instead of filled.
Regarding javascript replacement of circles to something else -- unfortunately It is beyond my javascript skills.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is "such an important bit". Traditionally different chart markers (and line styles) were used for printed materials when the chart was printed black and white and it was difficult to distinguish between series. With color and interactivity, this functionality shouldn't be a requirement.

Comment: I come from scientific plotting background, where plots tend to be very rich. And different symbols and colors are both used nowadays to convey a certain message. To me, absense of different plotting symbols is a big deal, but I guess Google didn't have scientific-like plotting in mind when designing the API.

Comment: Not to sidetrack the discussion, but when creating interactive graphs, the beauty is that you can use interactivity to minimize the data density while still allowing people to explore the data. The charts API is great for improving interactivity, but it isn't intended to replace R or excel or other more 'traditional' software packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of image charts. You can change the color and shape of the markers using this.Refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/scatter_charts#gcharts_shape_markers). An example for the different shape markers

[image]

[Click](http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxt=x,y&chs=300x150&cht=s&chco=FF0000%7C0000FF&chd=t:12,75,23,68,34,87,41,96,71,9%7C98,27,56,58,18,60,34,79,74,76&chdl=Cats%7CDogs&chm=o,FFFFFF,0,4,0%7Co,FF0000,0,0:4,8%7Cd,0000FF,0,5:9,10) here to see this. For more google charts related queries take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is an old obsolete version of gcharts that I mention in my post